# Can I call a method without triggering its event listeners?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, event-handling, osc

Is there any sort of flag or way to call a method without triggering any event handlers?

**FOR EXAMPLE**
I'm handling a `controlTextDidChange` method and checking to see if the character returned by a keystroke is valid. If it's not, I remove it; if it is, I append a word. The problem is that when I change the text while in `controlTextDidChange`, `controlTextDidChange` is called again and the program will loop indefinitely. I know I can use an instance variable to get around this, but is there any sort of flag or way to call a method without triggering any event handlers?

Comment: How are you in a loop?  If the text is valid, then don't change it, and your loop ends.  How does making the text valid mean that you're going to have to make the text valid infinity times?

Comment: The text being validated is a `char`. If its a valid `char` I append a word to it, thus changing the text and invoking the event handler again.

Comment: Then your validity logic is wrong;  Once the text is valid then, as @stevesliva said, you should not change the text again.  I.e. "text changed" -> "validity check" -> "invalid, fix it" -> "text changed" -> "validity check" -> "S'OK; don't change anything" -> done.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the logic. In my textfield I don't want to have to type the whole next world, only the first letter. Say for example that the next word is "hello". Then if I press "q", that's not valid because "hello" doesn't begin with "q", so I delete "q". But if I press "h" then that's valid, and the program then appends "ello", thus changing the textfield's text from "h" to "hello". But all of that is beside the question. It's simply an example to illustrate a case when I want to selectively inhibit event handlers for a particular method call.

Comment: So, getting away from the example I gave, is there any sort of way to call a method without triggering its listeners? I know *for example* I if I set the text using dot-notation `myTextField.stringValue = @"some string"` that `controlTextDidChange` isn't called. But is there a more general way to achieve this, perhaps with some identifier like `__silent [myObject myMethod];`?

Comment: No.  Not really.  You could create a category that swizzles `myMethod` but you'd need to know how to implement everything but the notification, and that'd be difficult if you don't have the `myMethod` code.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm sure there are "internal" system listeners that would be affected by such a thing. :-\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand the comment into a quick answer.

You have a method that issues a notification by design.  You want it to not issue that notification. You don't have an alternative available that does the same thing w/o the notification. If you want it to never issue that notification, and you have access to the code for the method, you could [swizzle](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) the method to a version where you've just commented out the notification.  Of course, if you had the code, you could just add another method, and call that one.   So you don't have the code, and all that's moot.

Can't you just bracket that invocation in code that removes the listener and then restores the listener?  In other words, **psuedocode** like this:

```
[self.controlThingy removeObserver:self]
[self.controlThingy myMethod]
[self.controlThingy addObserver:self]
```

You've then made self deaf to notifications for that one invocation of myMethod.  I've done similar things with bindings and KVO.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, and it's cleaner than toggling an instance BOOL. I guess ultimately whether Apple did it using a `__silent` identifier or I do it this way, ultimately someone will have to implement some version of this.